# Error finding a timestamp from the stream table

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

with reference to the fql stream table (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/) i'm trying to get the created_time timestamp from the graph api explorer and it returns nothing when i use the 'type' table.

```
SELECT created_time FROM stream WHERE source_id={MY_GROUP_ID} AND type=11
```

is this a facebook bug or anything i missed? because when i use type=308 it successfully returns the created_time.

Thanks

Comment: This data is probably hidden by design, knowing Facebook.

Comment: @cpilko so there's no way of getting the created time data?

Comment: I doubt it. As a policy, Facebook doesn't reveal create times for a number of Facebook-related events. If they wanted you to get at this, they would make it available directly in the `group` table.